# Array gets ints from assignments of other variables in main. How is it possible?

Tags: c

I'm getting crazy with C. I'm writing code for my battleship DOS app. I'm using a int matrix (10x10) to build the field, but a weird thing happens. When I assign a value to an other variable, some points in the field change their value.

I don't know how it's possible.

I use to fill the matrix with '1' (int value), so I print a char to simulate a "sea point" on the battleship field. Here's the problem: some unwanted ints appear on the field.
I removed all the functions from the game, leaving only "printfield". It still happens. Please help!

(i'm italian, i tried to translate the variables names to make things easier. i'm sorry if i did some english errors. I also added a lot of printfield functions to see how the field changes during the app execution)

Here the code: (note: changing, for example, the "pos_x" assignment, the unwanted values change)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int printfield(int camp[][9]);
int fill(int campo[][9]);

int main()
{

    int continua;
    int field1a[9][9];

    fill(field1a);

    printfield(field1a);
    continua=0;                           //what do this assignment do?????
    while(continua==0)
    {
        printfield(field1a);
        system("pause");
        int pos_x=7;                  //what do this assignment do????? 
        printfield(field1a);
        int pos_y=3;                    //what do this assignment do?????
        printfield(field1a);

        system("pause");
    }
    printfield(field1a);


    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    printfield(field1a);

    system("pause");
}

int printfield(int camp[][9])
{
    printf("\n\n\n"); 
    printf("   ");
    int word; 

    for(word=97;word<=106;word++)
    {
        printf("%c ", (char)word);
    }

    int q, r;
    for(q=0;q<=9;q++)
    {
        for(r=0;r<=9;r++)
        {
            if(r==0) 
            {
                printf("\n");
                if(q!=9)       //to print '10' (the row number) correctly spaced -see the different number of spaces I put into the next printf
                {
                    printf("%d  ", q+1);  //printf with 2 space for numbers 1-9
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%d ", q+1); //printf with 1 space for number 10
                }

            }
            switch(camp[r][q])
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("~ ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("0 ");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf("S ");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf("- ");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printf("X ");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printf("S ");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    printf("- ");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    printf("X ");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("E ");
                    break;
            }
        }       
    }
}

int fill(int campo[][9])
{
    int f, h;
    for(h=0;h<=9;h++)
    {
        for(f=0;f<=9;f++)
        {
            campo[f][h]=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see "10x10" and `int field1a[9][9];` ???

Comment: Off by one, in both dimensions.

Comment: This `h=0;h<=9` does not look good.

Comment: I use ten elements, so an array 0-9.

Comment: An array of elements of type `T` 10x10 is define like this: `T array[10][10];`

Comment: @alk isnt it right? h goes from 0 to 9, so ten elements.

Comment: 10 elements require 10 "slots". `T array[9]` creates an array with 9 "slots". Don't mistake zero-indexing for capacity.

Comment: @alk thank you for help. I will try to change it right now. Just a question: what do the element myarray[10][10] would contain?

Comment: If you define `T a[2][2];` you have the two times two equals *four* elements `a[0][0]`, `a[0][1]`, `a[1][0]`, `a[1][1]`. You have *no* (valid) elements `a[2][something]` and/or `a[something][2]`.!

Comment: @noisypixy i'm a bit confused since my unidimensional array usually worked well. Maybe it was a case. So 'T array[9]' create only 9 slots? What do i have in array[0] and in array[9]?

Comment: ok! so the last elements are not valid! I think i should read again some array theory stuff

Comment: If you do `T a[2];` and then do `a[2] = 1;` this invokes undefined behaviour, anything can happen from then on, from nothing to crash. During compile time the compiler would not necessarily point you to this bug. Correct indexing is left to the programmer's responsibility in C. Doing C is doing dangerous ... ;-)

Comment: @alk i'm new to the site. Is there a way to appreciate your answers?       (i use C because of school reasons :D)

Comment: If you like a comment, if you think "*it adds something useful to a question or answer*", just upvote it by clicking the triangle to the left of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign in a `matrix[9][9]` a number in a position [10].Remember a int [10] represents an array who starts at 0 until 9.
So, an array [9] starts at 0 to 8.
So you should or **correct the matrix** to be an `matrix[10][10]` or correct the for statement like that:

```
`for(q=0;q<9;q++)` (LESS **not** LESS EQUAL)
```

I hope I've helped you. I am not a native and my english is not good also.